# PHP fopen invalide arguments when using dynamic string

Tags: php, arguments, fopen

I am trying to dynamically create migration files, and I encounter a problem with the fopen function, whenever I call the function with a dynamic string for the name of the file I get the following error:

```
"failed to open stream: Invalid Argument.
```

now the wierd thing is, when I take the file_name string that caused the error, and put it fixed in the fopen function, it works and creates the file.

here is the part of the code that fails:

```
public function add_tables($from, $to) {
        $migration_name = $this->generate_migration_name($from, $to);
        $migration_file = fopen($migration_name, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $migration_content = "...";
        fwrite($migration_file, $migration_content);
   }
 public function generate_migration_name($from, $to) {
            $current_date = Date('Y_m_d_His');
            return $current_date."_create_msl_".$from."_to_".$to."_table.php";
        }
```

am I doing anything wrong?

UPDATE: the `$to` and `$from` are two strings im reading from a text file using fgets function. example for string that failed:

```
2017_02_22_154148_create_msl_yeshut_yatzran_to_mimshak_table.php
```

when I put it fixed in the fopen function the file is created successfully.

Comment: What's inside `$migration_name`? Are you sure it's a string? _(I think it is, but.. you know... the magic)_

Comment: Update the question with values `$from` and `$to` that result with the error.

Comment: @AlexBlex updated.

Comment: Did you echo the generate_migration_name($from, $to)?

Comment: @LucaJung yes and the echo was what I expected, like the example string I have posted in the update.

Comment: @BoooYaKa Ok, and are you sure that there are no spaces in the filename? It can be caused by the fgets function.

Comment: @LucaJung yes, I even tried running the string through str_replace(' ', '', $migration_name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have spaces in your filename. You can remove them by using trim:

```
public function generate_migration_name($from, $to) {
  $current_date = Date('Y_m_d_His');
  return $current_date."_create_msl_".trim($from)."_to_".trim($to)."_table.php";
}
```

Comment: trim did the work! I tried to remove white spaces with str_replace but with no success. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The file you are trying to create is not in your server or check file permissions

Comment: When I try to use the function with a fixed string it creates the file successfuly, so I do not think it has to do with the file no being there or permissions.